# I came across 'this' thing

Tags: terraria

I was exploring a cave (curved hole going deep in ground). I encountered these three 'things'. What should I call them?

[image: Screenshot of 3 red glowing hearts]

Comment: It seems I can't do anything about them at the moment. its protection blocks refuse to be mined

Comment: You either need to use explosives, or the safer and saner way is to buy Purification Powder from the Dryad (moves in after defeating the Eye), and use that to convert the stone to normal grey stone.

Comment: Or get a better pickaxe, then you can just mine through the Crimstone

Comment: @JonK except don'you need to kill the brain before you can get a good enough pickaxe? I'm not sure if enough kills of the eye might do but somehow I feel the first summoning of the brain needs either powder or explosives.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Those are [Crimson Hearts](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Crimson_Heart). They're roughly equivalent to the Shadow Orbs that you find underground near the Corruption. Every third one smashed will spawn the [Brain of Cthulhu](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Brain_of_Cthulhu) boss.